# Images on zooming show different colors and unwanted vertical and horizontal lines in latex (Overleaf)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, overleaf, resolution

[image]

I had a set of images (as shown in the image below) to be put in a document. The images are saved as png files. When I zoom the images at various different degrees of zoom I see different patterns of horizontal and vertical lines and the intensity of the various white points (all the white points have same intensity) starts to vary - some appears very blue or grayish as you can see in the image. I want all the points to remain white itself at all zoom levels and I do not want the vertical and horizontal partitioning lines. I was working on the document using overleaf. I used tikzpicture package. Can someone help me? If there is any more information I need to provide can you please let me know?

I have included a snippet of the code I have used - (the below code is for adding one image out of the 5)

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.15\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\includegraphics[scale=.45]{Directory/Image_1.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Source of your problem are images, not LaTeX code of your document. For better quality of images you should use vector format for images (as are pdf or eps). What you see also depends on preview program etc.

Comment: With or without LaTeX, any bitmap image (PNG, JPG, etc.) will always be pixelated when zoomed too much, and will always lose pixels when zoomed too little. That is,  always lost quality when zoomed.  If the viewer is able to do on the fly a good resampling could help, but it cannot do miracles. You cannot do much about, except check that the original image have 300 ppp and show it without scaling, or in case of charts and draws, use vectorial images, for instance, a SVG exported to PDF (but not a PNG exported to PDF).